# How to restart openvpn service (or any service) running under "nobody" user?

Tags: server, services, openvpn

On my Ubuntu 16.04 server, I have the OpenVPN service running as the user `nobody`.  How can I restart the service or reload the config file for the service using, for instance, `systemctl`?

An `openvpn` process is running, but I don't know how to access it.

```
310 nobody    20   0   44440   3184   1968 S  0.0  0.3   1263:30 openvpn
```

The command `su nobody` does not work because no password is set.  Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 15):

Try this, I've noticed that `restart` doesn't work for me.

```
sudo systemctl stop openvpn@server
sudo systemctl enable openvpn@server.service
sudo systemctl start openvpn@server
```

Answer (score 10):

OpenVPN is a templatized service under `systemd`.  The services are named `openvpn@config.service`.  So you should restart your
`/etc/openvpn/myvpn.conf` instance with:

```
systemctl restart openvpn@myvpn.service
```

Comment: The trouble is using systemctl status openvpn@myvpn.service doesn't reveal an active service when doing this under my login or under root user, as I assume the service is running under the nobody user

Answer (score 5):

Go to the this directory and take a look at files:

```
sudo su

cd /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants

ls
```

there should be a file in this format (could be different depend on openvpn version):

openvpn-server@server.service

or

openvpn@server.service

if you see multiple files in this format, it's because you probably use this code before:

```
sudo systemctl enable openvpn-something@server.service
```

this self-made files (created by enable) does nothing and could be removed later. But for now you should find the one works well with this commands without causing any error:

```
sudo systemctl stop <openvpn-server@server.service>
sudo systemctl start <openvpn-server@server.service>
```

and replace  with all files in this format (starts with openvpn and ends with .service) in the directory. The one that truly stops and starts openvpn service is the file you need and others could be removed (you shouldn't have made them in first place by enabling them):

```
sudo rm <openvpn-selfMadeFiles@server.service>
```

Be careful to not to remove the one that is making the service start and stop

Answer (score 1):

Log in as `sudo su`.

Run `service openvpnas restart` or `service openvpn restart`.

Comment: This actually doesn't work under Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: this works for me on ubuntu 2022

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I found that if you're running docker on the same machine, there's some kind of conflict.

So if you're running the Docker service, I suggest you first stop Docker and then try starting OpenVPN server.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do if you don't know the exact service name or are lazy like I am.
Run `systemctl status openvpn*`
The * match up the service closest to that string.
Works for the other functions like stop & start.

Comment: It does not work for me: `Unit openvpn-install.sh.service could not be found.`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was `openvpn-server@server.service`, I found it in the `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` directory